# what is worng in ajaxSubmit calling?

Tags: jquery, ajaxsubmit

```
$scope.submitTheForm = function(htmlcode){  
        var idOfForm = "formOfCalCPDF";
        var dataPassed = $.param({'htmlcode':htmlcode,'mode':'getpdf'});
        alert("coming here");
        $(idOfForm).ajaxSubmit({
            url: 'ggs.erm.payrollJava.Taxsummary',
            type: "POST",
             data: dataPassed,
            error:function (){},
            success: function (data){}
        });
    };
```

When ever I call this function , although alert is executing,but not POST request, do you see any kind of problem with it?

Comment: who is calling `submitTheForm `? do you have a default action that needs to be prevented like a actual form submit

Comment: also what is the value of `idOfForm`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I forgot to add # :) that was a subtle mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `id` selector try this:-

```
$scope.submitTheForm = function(htmlcode){  
    var idOfForm = "formOfCalCPDF";
    var dataPassed = $.param({'htmlcode':htmlcode,'mode':'getpdf'});
    alert("coming here");
    $('#'+idOfForm).ajaxSubmit({
        url: 'ggs.erm.payrollJava.Taxsummary',
        type: "POST",
         data: dataPassed,
        error:function (){},
        success: function (data){}
    });
};
```

Comment: Now I see my mistake.. It's embarrassing .